# GEE exporting geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've been trying to export my geometries from GEE to drive (or any other method) by   converting my geometry to a FeatureCollection and using the following code

```
Export.FeatureCollection.toDrive({
  collection: geometry4sub,
  folder: "GEE data",
});
```

However, I get the following error message: Cannot read property 'toDrive' of undefined

Comment: Can you try Export.table.toDrive(collection, description, folder, fileNamePrefix, fileFormat, selectors) method? Seems like Export.FeatureCollection.toDrive is not in the Docs.

Comment: This does not work because I'm trying to export a hand drawn geometry and not a table. Unless there is a way to convert my handmade geometry into a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the geometry to a feature in a feature collection and export that to the drive. You are getting that error because Export.FeatureCollection does not exist and so there is no property "toDrive" of something that does not exist. The easiest way to do what you want would be

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry4sub);

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:fc,
  folder: "GEE data"
});
```